# Javascript innerHTML and JSON parsed string difference

Tags: javascript, json, smarty, decode, innerhtml

I use JSmart (SMARTY JS port) in my project. I have two options to obtain the template:

1. insert it inside

   <script id="tpl" type="text/x-jsmart-tmpl">
   ...
   </script>

and pull it by

```
document.getElementById('tpl').innerHTML
```

2. receive it in JSON value

I met an issue with the second option: item value after JSON.Parse contains special chars like \r \n or \t, includng / etc. JSmart does not undestand this.

In case of pulling from innerHTML the result string handled fine.

Small example:
JSON parsed value:

```
<!-- \r\n SMARTY template\r\n\tdata object\r\n
```

innerHTML pulled value:

```
<!-- 
   SMARTY template
      data object
```

How I could convert JSON parsed value to the string equal I got from innerHTML?

Comment: Please add a JSON template !

Comment: See on pasteBin: http://pastebin.com/bYtDgAY4

Comment: Node.js or Browser ?

Comment: @Ismail-RBOUH - Browser

Answer (score 0):

The template file is not `JSON`, is a smarty template. However, you can fetch it from a file/url like this:

```
$.get("template_url", function(tplText) {
    var tpl = new jSmart( tplText );
    //Compile the tpl with your data object
    var res = tpl.fetch( data );
    //res is your compiled HTML
    //document.write( res );
});
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/3wpfu604/

Comment: I receive this template via $.getJSON as part of received object:
{data: "...", tpl: "..."}

Comment: Do not use getJSON ! the template it's not a valid JSON instead use get !

Comment: Again, I receive JSON string like {data: "...", tpl: "..."}, and $.getJSON decodes it into JS object X. I try to use X.data and X.tpl

Comment: My innerHTML looks like http://pastebin.com/bYtDgAY4 
but X.tpl like http://pastebin.com/4PKhqqQx

Comment: Very strange. I guess this is something like double escaping. Will try to discover my code where it could be...

Comment: Ismail, thanks a lot for your assistance. I found a bug, it was really double escaping. I have to change server code to Base64 the template first, and then to escape the result. This way it works fine. Thanks again & good luck!